# int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, image-processing, computer-vision

I am a beginner in python and am trying to find similarity between images by testing against a test_pic and a database containing images.  I have passed images from a directory and compared it using SIFT features

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageStat
from PIL import ImageFilter
import os

def get_imlist(path):
    """    Returns a list of filenames for 
        all jpg images in a directory. """

    return [os.path.join(f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.png')]

def fe(file_name):
    im = Image.open(file_name)
    im = im.convert('L')
    w, h = 300, 300
    im = im.resize((w, h))
    imst = ImageStat.Stat(im)
    sr = imst.mean[0]
    def foo(t):
        if t < sr * 2 / 3: return 0
        if t <= sr: return 1
        if t < sr * 4 / 3: return 2
        return 3
    im = im.point(foo)
    res = [[0] * 4 for i in range(10)]
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            k = im.getpixel((x, y))
            res[y / 60][k] += 1
            res[x / 60 + 5][k] += 1
    return res

def ff(file_name):
    im = Image.open(file_name)
    im = im.convert('L')
    w, h = 300, 300
    im = im.resize((w, h))
    im = im.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
    sr = ImageStat.Stat(im).mean[0]
    res = 0
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if im.getpixel((j, i)) > sr:
                res += 1
    #im.show()
    return res

test_pic = '128.png' #testing this pic against all pics in our db;
path='D:/ex'
imlist=[]
db=[]
imlist=get_imlist(path)
for file in imlist:
    x = [0, file]
    db.append(x)  
z = [fe(db[i][1]) for i in range(len(db))]
test_z = fe(test_pic)
for k in range(len(db)):
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(4):
            db[k][0] += abs(z[k][i][j] - test_z[i][j])
db.sort()

print
print '1st-line sifting [by fe()]'
print '--------------------'
print test_pic
print '--------------------'
for k in range(len(db)):
    if db[k][0] < 20 * 3600:
        print '%12s %7.2f' % (db[k][1], db[k][0] / 3600.0,)
    else:
        break
print '--------------------'
print
print
print '2nd-line sifting [by ff()]'
print '--------------------'
print test_pic
print '--------------------'
test_t = ff(test_pic)
for k in range(len(db)):
    if db[k][0] < 5 * 3600:
        print '%12s' % (db[k][1],)
    elif db[k][0] < 20 * 3600:
        t = ff(db[k][1])
        if abs(t - test_t) * 200.0 / (t + test_t) < 20:
            print '%12s' % (db[k][1],)
    else:
        break
print '--------------------'

raw_input('\nPress...\n')
```

Comment: You need to show us the *full* traceback of the exception please.

Comment: Can you include all of the code? I see no reference to `__getitem` in what you've posted. Also include the line number at which the error occurs, if possible.

Comment: I have a list of .png images in a directory which i have stored into a list -imlist

Comment: `fe(db[i][1])` assuming the error is from there. when `ì=0` you're trying to index a integer.

Comment: @Jonas Please edit the question - it is very hard to parse code in comments!

Comment: @Jonas [edit] your question please.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: It just means the OP used `integervalue[index]` somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience i have edited my code . @M4rtini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess:

```
db = [0,file]
i = 0
z = [fe(db[i][1]) for i in range(len(db))]
      # ^ here
```

When `i == 0`, `db[i] == 0`. You are then trying to index into an integer - `0[1]` - which, behind the scenes, effectively calls `0.__getitem__(1)`. Integers don't implement `__getitem__`, so this fails with the error you are seeing.

---

Your code revision seems a bit odd, why do:

```
for file in imlist:
    db = [[0,file]]   
    z = [fe(db[i][1]) for i in range(len(db))]
```

And not simply:

```
for file in imlist:
    z = [fe(file)]
```

However, without the full traceback, it is hard to precisely diagnose your error.

Comment: i have removed i=0 . That was not the part of the code. I made editions to my question

Comment: @jonrsharpe- In db variable what i get is [0,filename1.png], [filename2.png] and goes on .What i want is to compare all those images to the Test_pic and compare their similiarity

Comment: @Jonas What is the 0 for? And you never actually append\extend the list, so you always have a list of length 1.

Comment: @jonrsharpe- I cant do-   for file in imlist:
                              z = [fe(file)]                           Coz i have a list of images to be compared in DB and i have to check test_pic  with many images

Comment: @M4rtini -This is a code taken from http://sourceforge.net/projects/imsim/files/                           I Just made editions to the code to take in a database of files from a directory . Can i know what editions should i make to the above code

Comment: @Jonas that may be your aim, but as M4rtini points out that isn't what you're currently doing - for each image, you create a new list with a single two-item sublist. If you want `append` the output of `fe` to `z`, you should explicitly do that!

Comment: @Jonas `db = [[0, _file] for _file in imlist]`this does what you want (i think), using list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_imlist(path):
    """    Returns a list of filenames for 
        all jpg images in a directory. """

    return [[0, 0 ,os.path.join(path, f)] for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.png')]
```

If you simply change your `get_imlist` function like this. It returns a structure similar to what the code you linked in one of the comments used. So you should be able to use that code without any further edits.

Comment: Thanks for all your help . I did it using my normal file did some editions and  appended the value to db. I Will edit the running code and make it usable for others.

Comment: @Jonrsharpe-Thank you too . I would appreciate if you guys give me some reputation so that i can vote for you guys who are really such a help to beginners like me.